# Triggering after update - difference between UI and Setup for Picklist value changes

Tags: picklist, after-trigger, order-of-execution

I have discovered that if I change a picklist value from the UI, it triggers apex after updates, as well as Process Builder flows, while if I use the Picklist field window, and 'del/replace' the picklist value - that does not trigger the after update triggers.

Do you know if this is normal? or is it a bug?
Is that the same behaviour for Custom fields as well as standard fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm) in the documentation.

Renaming/Replacing a picklist doesn't invoke triggers(I assume same is applicable for process builder)

Replacing / Renaming a pick list value is a global change and will not update the record history related list as well.

Below are two links which provides some more details on this:

- [Link 1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175633&language=en_US&type=1)
- [Link 2](http://www.simplysfdc.com/2014/06/salesforce-change-picklist-field.html)

See if this helps!